# Opencv VideoCapture Resolution Issue in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I am working with a computer vision project in vc++. I am using opencv to record video from webcam which is Logitech c925e and support 1080p recording. It works fine with python and C++ on OSX and Liunx. However, it just can record video in 960x720 on Windows 10 with opencv. Windows 10 build-in camera application record 1080p video. I am a beginner of Windows development. Is it has another library can record video in vc++?

It is my code:

```
cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);

if(!cpa.isOpened()) 
    return;

cap >> frame;
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);

while(true) {
   cap >> frmae;
   cv::imshow("Test", frame);
}
```